# not inserting value to mysql in ionic 3

Tags: mysql, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

> not inserting value to mysql in ionic 3 
>   not inserting value to mysql in ionic 3

**not inserting value to mysql in ionic 3** not inserting value to mysql in 
    ionic 3

```
      <ion-item *ngIf="selectedCities">
              <ion-label floating>Cities</ion-label>
              <ion-icon name="ios-navigate" item-left></ion-icon>
              <ion-select  formControlName="city" [(ngModel)]="sCity">
                <ion-option [value]="sCity" *ngFor="let sCity of 
selectedCities">{{sCity.name}}</ion-option>
              </ion-select>
            </ion-item>
```

Comment: saveEntry() {
    let name: string = this.form.controls["name"].value,
      country: string = this.form.controls["country"].value,
      state: string = this.form.controls["state"].value,
      city: string = this.form.controls["city"].value,
      experience: string = this.form.controls["experience"].value
  
      console.log("save Entry :"+ name, country, state, city, experience)

    this.createEntry(name, country, state, city, experience);
  }

Comment: its not taking value of selected list. only displaying 'object'...

Comment: Put your `code` in the question above?

Comment: Have you tried `<ion-option [value]="sCity.name"`? Because `sCity` is obviously an object and not a string.

Comment: `setDistrictValues(sState) {
    this.selectedDistricts = this.districts.filter(district => district.state_id == sState.id);
    console.log(this.selectedDistricts);
  }`

Comment: thankUou for helping.  
if i add `<ion-option [value]="sCity.name"` above code will not work coz am selecting country,state,city

Answer (score 0):

I formatted it properly:

```
saveEntry() { 
  let name: string = this.form.controls["name"].value,
  country: string = this.form.controls["country"].value,
  state: string = this.form.controls["state"].value,
  city: string = this.form.controls["city"].value,
  experience: string = this.form.controls["experience"].value
  console.log("save Entry :"+ name, country, state, city, experience)
  this.createEntry(name, country, state, city, experience); 
}
```

Would change it to this:

```
saveEntry() {
  let name: string = this.form.controls["name"].value;
  let country: string = this.form.controls["country"].value;
  let state: string = this.form.controls["state"].value;
  let city: string = this.form.controls["city"].value;
  let experience: string = this.form.controls["experience"].value;

  console.log("save Entry :"+ name, country, state, city, experience);

  this.createEntry(name, country, state, city, experience); 
}
```

Please use `;` after every command.

What is your console log showing? What does `createEntry()` do?

Comment: Please show the code of the `createEntry()` function.

Answer (score 0):

As Ma Kobi asked in the above comment, can you please show the createEntry() function? It looks like the data you are sending is fine so the error is probably in the SQL statement in your createEntry() function.

Are you using SQLite in your app or posting your data to a mysql server by http? SQLite example below

```
this.sqlite.create({
            name: 'addresses.db',
            location: 'default'
        }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
            db.executeSql('INSERT INTO experiences VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)',[name, country, state, city, experience])
            .then(res => {
                console.log('Data Saved into Experiences Table!');
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            });
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
        });
```

Maybe that helps.

Comment: This is a rather old question, that will unlikely garner a response by the original poster. You should avoid asking further questions in your answers, and stick to just providing an answer. Asking for clarification should be done in the comments. Be aware: Stackoverflow is not a forum, and extended discussion should not be done through answers.